MAUI Android Foreground Service Stops Running in Background After a Few Minutes and Misses API Calls
I am developing an application using .NET MAUI that needs to continuously listen for missed calls and send the caller's phone number to an API endpoint. I have implemented a foreground service to keep the app running in the background. The service works for a few minutes, but then stops running when the device goes into idle mode or when the app is not opened, resulting in missed API calls.
I have tried using a foreground service with a persistent notification, but it does not seem to keep the service running consistently.
Here is my implementation:
MainActivity.cs
using Android;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Provider; // For Settings.Secure
using AndroidX.Core.App;
using AndroidX.Core.Content;
using Android.Widget;

namespace MissedCallSMSService.Platforms.Android
{
    [Activity(Label = "MissedCallSMSService", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        const int RequestCallLogPermissionId = 0;
        const int RequestNotificationAccessId = 1;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Start the MissedCallService
            StartMissedCallService();

            // Check and request permissions
            CheckAndRequestPermissions();
        }

        private void StartMissedCallService()
        {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MissedCallService));
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                StartForegroundService(serviceIntent);
            }
            else
            {
                StartService(serviceIntent);
            }
        }

        void CheckAndRequestPermissions()
        {
            if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.ReadPhoneState) != Permission.Granted ||
                ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.ReadCallLog) != Permission.Granted)
            {
                ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[]
                {
                    Manifest.Permission.ReadPhoneState,
                    Manifest.Permission.ReadCallLog
                }, RequestCallLogPermissionId);
            }
            else
            {
                CheckAndRequestNotificationPermission();
            }
        }

        void CheckAndRequestNotificationPermission()
        {
            if (!IsNotificationServiceEnabled())
            {
                // Guide the user to the notification access settings
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ActionNotificationListenerSettings);
                StartActivityForResult(intent, RequestNotificationAccessId);
            }
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            if (requestCode == RequestCallLogPermissionId)
            {
                if (grantResults.Length > 0 && grantResults[0] == Permission.Granted)
                {
                    // Permissions granted
                    CheckAndRequestNotificationPermission();
                }
                else
                {
                    // Permissions denied
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Permissions denied. The app requires call log access to function properly.", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                }
            }
        }

        private bool IsNotificationServiceEnabled()
        {
            string pkgName = PackageName;
            string flat = Settings.Secure.GetString(ContentResolver, "enabled_notification_listeners");
            if (flat != null && flat.Contains(pkgName))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}

MissedCallService.cs
using Android;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Util;
using AndroidX.Core.App;
using AndroidX.Core.Content;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MissedCallSMSService.Platforms.Android
{
    [Service]
    public class MissedCallService : Service
    {
        private MissedCallReceiver mReceiver;
        private const int NotificationId = 1;
        private string NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "1000";
        private int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
        private string NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME = "notification";

        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            // Run the service in the foreground to ensure it continues running
            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "missed_call_channel")
                .SetContentTitle("Missed Call Service")
                .SetContentText("Listening for missed calls")
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.maui_splash_image)
                .Build();

            // StartForeground(NotificationId, notification);
            StartForegroundService();

            // Start listening for missed calls
            ListenForMissedCalls();

            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }

        private void StartForegroundService()
        {
            var notifcationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                CreateNotificationChannel(notifcationManager);
            }

            var notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
            notification.SetAutoCancel(false);
            notification.SetOngoing(true);
            notification.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Mipmap.appicon);
            notification.SetContentTitle("ForegroundService");
            notification.SetContentText("Foreground Service is running");
            StartForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification.Build());
        }

        private void CreateNotificationChannel(NotificationManager notificationManager)
        {
            var channel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME,
            NotificationImportance.High);
            notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        private void ListenForMissedCalls()
        {
            mReceiver = new MissedCallReceiver();

            var filter = new IntentFilter();
            filter.AddAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");

            RegisterReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

            // Check periodically if permissions are granted and notify if not
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(5000); // Sleep for 5 seconds before checking again

                    if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.ReadPhoneState) != Permission.Granted ||
                        ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.ReadCallLog) != Permission.Granted)
                    {
                        NotifyUserToGrantPermissions();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        private void NotifyUserToGrantPermissions()
        {
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                var channel = new NotificationChannel("missed_call_channel", "Missed Call Channel", NotificationImportance.High)
                {
                    Description = "Notifications for missed call permissions"
                };
                notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
            }

            var notificationIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            notificationIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTask);
            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

            var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "missed_call_channel")
                .SetContentTitle("Missed Call Service")
                .SetContentText("Please grant phone state and call log permissions.")
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.maui_splash_image)
                .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .SetAutoCancel(true);

            notificationManager.Notify(NotificationId, builder.Build());
        }

        public override void OnDestroy()
        {
            base.OnDestroy();
            if (mReceiver != null)
            {
                UnregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
            }
        }
    }
}

I need the service to continuously run in the background and listen for missed calls even when the phone is idle or the app is not opened. I also want to ensure that the necessary permissions are requested and granted, including notification access permissions. What changes or best practices should I follow to achieve this?

Use Foreground Service within the service, use a Broadcast Receiver to listen for the TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED intent also you need to request READ_CALL_LOG permissions. Use WorkManager if targeting Android 12.

Which .net version does your maui project use, .net7 or .net8?

Apologies for the delayed response. I'm relatively new to MAUI technology and would appreciate your assistance in resolving this issue. Our current setup using .NET 8. Thank you in advance for your help.

Regarding the function of reading call records, you also need to add a request for READ_CALL_LOG permission in the project.
